# cUrl запрос с IP адреса подсети

Tags: c++, linux, curl, ip, libcurl

Имеется ОС Linux, приложение на C++, libcurl и сетевой интерфейс на котором доступна подсеть адресов. Как сделать запрос с конкретного IP адреса из подсети не добавляя его в интерфейсах ОС.

```
curl_easy_setopt(this->Curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "192.168.1.228");
```

Так не работает пока не добавить IP в интерфейсах.

Comment: Я что-то не совсем понял, Вы хотите, чтобы в заголовках IP был адрес "левой" машины? Если так, то, кажется, Вам нужно raw-сокеты использовать.

Comment: Нет, я могу с помощью ip addr add добавить адрес и это будет реальный белый ip и все будет работать как нужно, но можно ли как-то обойтись без процедуры добавления при отправке запроса и получении ответа?

Comment: без добавления адреса ответ не дойдет до приложения

Comment: Вам на каком уровне нужно знать IP адрес? Если на уровне сетевого стека (например, адрес, который возвращает функция [`getpeername`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html), то никак. Этот адрес конструируется из полей заголовков IP и TCP. Если же на уровне HTTP, то укажите нужный адрес в HTTP заголовке `X-Real-IP` или `X-Forwarded-For`